# Magick.NET Dll Unable to load on powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

Download the following link in many versions of the DLL, can not load successfully
https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET

Prompt the following error

```
ERROR: Add-Type : Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
Magick.ps1 (1, 1): ERROR: At Line: 1 char: 1
ERROR: + Add-Type -Path ".\Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU.dll"
```

Powershell CODE:

```
Add-Type -Path ".\Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU.dll"

$image = New-Object ImageMagick.MagickImage c:\bg.jpg

$image.Format = 'jpeg'
$image.Quality = 99
$image.Write('c:\bg-q99.jpg')

$image.Rotate(90)
$image.Write('c:\bg-90.jpg')

$image = New-Object ImageMagick.MagickImage c:\bg.jpg
$image.Crop(200, 200, [ImageMagick.Gravity]::Center)
$image.Write('c:\bg-crop.jpg')

$image.Resize(200, 100)
$image.Write('c:\bg-200-100.jpg')

$image.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying, two DLL files should be placed before running successfully,
One is
Magick.NET.Core.dll
The other is
Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU.dll